# Switch list/grid view using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html-table

On one of my website pages, I present data on a table element, but I want to add a button to let user choose if he wants to see the data as a list (table) or a grid (ul>li>img). What is the best way to do that?

```
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td>datas 1</td>
                        <td><img src="image1.jpg"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>datas 2</td>
                        <td><img src="image2.jpg"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>datas 3</td>
                        <td><img src="image3.jpg"></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td>datas 4</td>
                        <td><img src="image4.jpg"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
```

and if we switch with a toggle button:

```
                 <ul>
                    <li><img src="image1.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="image2.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="image3.jpg"></li>
                    <li><img src="image4.jpg"></li>
                </ul>
```

Do I have to make that with jQuery or CSS?

What I tried is to create a div element when page finish loading and create a list by getting img attribute in table element. Then I have my table and my new div (with diplay:none). When user clicks the button I made a display none on table and display block on my div. Is this is a correct way?

I think it's not very "cool" because I have duplicate content:

```
<table>...</table>
<div style="display:none">...</div>
```

what do you think about that?

Comment: Yes, that is the correct way. You could add a classname to both containing divs, and use the jQuery `toggleClass` method. That way, you can use transitions.

Answer (score 0):

What I would do in this situation would be to utilize the same markup and style differently depending on said 'view' (list/grid). Depending on the users selection you can style each accordingly.

(The solution here can be as simple as adding a class name on 'list/grid' to the body tag within the page when a user interacts with the said button!)

Although with your images already populate I would NOT hide that data, since it's already populated I would just minimize said image and turn it into a thumbnail. (No use in the browser rendering out the image and you just appending style='display:none;')

**Update:**

Just referenced craigslist to see how they handle this situation. In which they actually do style said images with 'display:none'. So depending on your client / project etc. display:none within the styles is up to you!

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Create two classes: "grid" and "list" and use ul markup. For grid create css table.

See sample code in jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maximkou/9CwXh/6/

Html:

```
<ul class="grid data-table">
    <li>
        <span class="caption">Caption</span>
        <span class="content">
            <img src="image1.jpg">
        </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="caption">Caption</span>
        <span class="content">
            <img src="image1.jpg">
            </span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <span class="caption">Caption</span>
        <span class="content">
            <img src="image1.jpg">
            </span>
    </li>

    <li>
        <span class="caption">Caption</span>
        <span class="content">
            <img src="image1.jpg">
            </span>
    </li>
</ul>

<a href="" class="toggleView">Toggle view to List</a>
```

JS:

```
$('.toggleView').bind('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var text = 'Toggle view to ';
    if ($('.data-table').hasClass('grid')){
        $(this).html(text + 'Grid');
        $('.data-table').removeClass('grid').addClass('list');
    } else {
        $(this).html(text + 'List');
        $('.data-table').removeClass('list').addClass('grid');
    }
});
```

CSS:

```
.grid {
    display: table;
    list-style-type: none;
}
.grid li {
    display: table-row;
}
.grid li span {
    width: 200px;
    display: table-cell;
}

.list li .caption {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: thanks! but here you change ul style. i have a table element and switching to a ul element.

Comment: @Axton56, I understand that, but the variant that I offer correctly, because you do not need to duplicate the output the same data and place unnecessary elements in dom.

Answer (score 0):

I recently needed to do the same thing. Much like you, I wanted the content to be retained while swapping the surrounding html. The CSS is mostly just for styling your table/grid. The real star of the show here is jQuery.

Take a look: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rymill2/R3J5m/

HTML

```
<div class="row"> 
    <a class="button-table" data-target="table"><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/100x50/282828/fff/?text=Table"></a>
    <a class="button-grid" data-target="grid"><img src="http://fakeimg.pl/100x50/282828/fff/?text=Grid"></a>
</div>
<div class="content">
    <table>
        <tr class="table-head">
            <th>Title</th>
            <th>Date</th>
            <th>Info</th>
        </tr>
        <tr class="result">
            <div class="settings"></div> <a class="link" href=""></a>

            <td class="title">Class Title</td>
            <td class="row">Item Details</td>
            <td class="row">Item Details</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="result">
            <div class="settings"></div> <a class="link" href=""></a>

            <td class="title">Class Title</td>
            <td class="row">Item Details</td>
            <td class="row">Item Details</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="result">
            <div class="settings"></div> <a class="link" href=""></a>

            <td class="title">Class Title</td>
            <td class="row">Item Details</td>
            <td class="row">Item Details</td>
        </tr>
        <tr class="result">
            <div class="settings"></div> <a class="link" href=""></a>

            <td class="title">Class Title</td>
            <td class="row">Item Details</td>
            <td class="row">Item Details</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.table-head, div, a, p, span {
    box-sizing:border-box !important;
}
.columns, .column {
    float:left;
    position:relative;
}
.h-100 {
    min-height:110px;
}
.three {
    width:25%;
}
a:hover {
    cursor:pointer;
    background:#e9e9e9;
}
a.toggle-table, a.toggle-grid {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    margin-right:6px;
    font-size:20px;
    padding:8px;
}
.settings, .link {
    display:none;
}
.grid {
    overflow:auto;
}
.grid .result {
    padding:2%;
    background:#e9e9e9;
    border:1px solid #333;
}
.grid .result:first-child {
    display:none;
}
.grid .result .title, .grid.result .row, .grid .result .link {
    position:relative;
    float:left;
    width:100%;
}
.grid .result .title {
    border-bottom:1px solid yellow;
    padding-bottom:2px;
    margin-bottom:2px;
    color:#282828;
    font-size:16px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.grid .result .row {
    color:#666;
    font-size:10px;
}
.table-head {
    background:#333;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left;
    font-size:12px;
}
```

JS

```
$('.button-table').click(function() {
$('.grid').replaceWith(function() {
    var html = '';
    $('div:first', this).each(function() {
        html += '<tr class="table-head">';
        $('div', this).each(function() {
            html += '<th>' + $(this).html() + '</th>';
        });
        html += '</tr>';
    });   
    $('div:not(:first)', this).each(function() {
        var innerHtml = '';
        $('div', this).each(function() {
            innerHtml += '<td>' + $(this).html() + '</td>';
        });
        if (innerHtml != '') {
        html += '<tr>' + innerHtml + '</tr>';
        }
    });
    return '<table>' + html + '</table>'; 
});
});

$('.button-grid').click(function() {
$('table').replaceWith(function() {
    var html = '';      
    $('tr', this).each(function() {
        html += '<div class="result three columns h-100">';
        $('th', this).each(function() {
            html += '<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>';
        });
        $('td', this).each(function() {
            html += '<div>' + $(this).html() + '</div>';
        });
        html += '</div>';
    });
    return '<div class="grid">' + html + '</div>';
});
});
```